# how do I escape a forward slash in xpath?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

How do I escape the forward slash character in an xpath query?  My tags contain a url, so I need to be able to do this.  I am using lxml in python.

Alternatively, is it possible for xpath to query a substring of the path?  Examples are below:

```
xml="""
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsa="http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007">
  <gsa:content name="reportName">bbb</gsa:content>
  <gsa:content name="collectionName">default_collection</gsa:content>
  <gsa:content name="reportDate">date_3_25_2009</gsa:content>
 </entry>
"""
```

When I run the following:

```
tree=fromstring(xml)
for elt in tree.xpath('//*'):
    elt.tag
```

It returns:

```
'{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry'
'{http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007}content'
'{http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007}content'
'{http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007}content'
```

Running `tree.xpath('/entry')` returns an empty list.

I need to be able to either query for '{http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom}entry' as the tag, or query for 'entry' anywhere in the tag.

Comment: Your tags don't contain a URL. The namespace URIs of your elements are URLs. The `{http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007}content` notation may be what's misleading you here. While useful, that notation not standard XML or XPath. The namespace URI is not part of the element name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into [`namespace prefixes`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes).

If you want an element that's in the `http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007` namespace you need to search for it like so:

```py
import lxml.etree as et

xml="""
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gsa="http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007">
  <gsa:content name="reportName">bbb</gsa:content>
  <gsa:content name="collectionName">default_collection</gsa:content>
  <gsa:content name="reportDate">date_3_25_2009</gsa:content>
 </entry>
"""

NS = {'rootns': 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom',
      'gsa': 'http://schemas.google.com/gsa/2007'}

tree = et.fromstring(xml)

for el in tree.xpath('//gsa:content', namespaces=NS):
    print el.attrib['name']

print len(tree.xpath('//rootns:entry', namespaces=NS))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works.  How do I set the namespace for the root? (the entry node)

Comment: You have to define another namespace prefix in `NS` and include it in your XPath expression.